# OnClick Listener Is Not Function As Expected

Tags: java, android, onclick, switch-statement, onclicklistener

I have an `onClickListener` set on a `TextView` (`mReadAgainButton`) which is supposed to reload a set of instructions from the beginning (initially displayed via an `onClickListener` on a `Button` called `mAssistUpdateButton`) however when clicking on the `TextView` `mReadAgainButton` nothing seems to happen.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mAssistUpdateButton) {

            // Update button for ICS and up is selected
            // Get the TextView in the Assist Update UI

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            String text = "";
            CharSequence styledText = text;
            switch (mInstructionNumber) {

            case 0:
                // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
                // 2nd set of instructions
                text =   String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                        TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 1:
                text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 2:
                // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

                setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
                String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                        getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
                TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
                assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
                mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
                mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
                mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        } else if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {
            // "LET'S DO THIS" Button in final instructions screen for ICS and
            // up is selected
            Values = getValues();
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
            try {
                showNotification();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();
        } else if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
            try {
                showNotification();
            } catch (SAXException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                showNotification();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();

        } else if (v == mReadAgainButton) {
            // go back to set of instructions if read again is selected

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            String text = "";
            CharSequence styledText = text;
            switch (mInstructionNumber) {

            case 0:
                // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
                // 2nd set of instructions
                text = String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                        TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 1:
                text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 2:
                // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

                setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
                String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                        getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
                TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
                assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
                mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
                mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
                mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

FULL SOURCE:

```
public class ConfigFinalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "ConfigFinalActivity";
    TelephonyManager tm;
    AlertDialog mErrorAlert = null;
    private Notification mNotification = null;
    private Button mXButton = null;
    private ImageView mAssistUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistInstrButton = null;
    private TextView mReadAgainButton = null;
    private int mInstructionNumber = 0;
    public static ArrayList<String> NameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> nameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ApnArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmscArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsportArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsproxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> portArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> proxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int count;
    public static int TotalSteps = 10;
    int i, g = 0, result = 0;

    public static ContentValues Values = new ContentValues();

    public static final Uri APN_TABLE_URI = Uri
            .parse("content://telephony/carriers");
    public static InputStream stream = null;
    UpdateActivity update;
    public static String status, queryResult = "";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        update = new UpdateActivity();
        getArrayLists();

        if (ApnArr.isEmpty() || mmscArr.isEmpty()) {

            tryagain();
        } else if (version < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

            SettingsDbAdapter.setArrayLists(nameArr, ApnArr, mmscArr,
                    mmsproxyArr, mmsportArr, proxyArr, portArr, count,
                    ConfigFinalActivity.this);
            // Update APN table
            try {
                result = updateTable();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }// Settings updated with this atomic call
            catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (result != -1) {
                status = "success";

            } else {
                status = "failure";
            }

            if (status.equals("success")) {
                completeUpdate();
            } else if (status.equals("failure")) {
                tryagain();

            }

        } else {// ICS and later versions

            // Reduce number of steps to 10
            TotalSteps = 10;
            setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);
            String assistUpdate = getString(R.string.instructions_1);
            mAssistUpdateButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
            mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
    }

    private void getArrayLists() {
        nameArr = update.getnameArr();
        ApnArr = update.getApnArr();
        mmscArr = update.getMMSCArr();
        mmsproxyArr = update.getMmscProxyArr();
        mmsportArr = update.getMmsPortArr();
        proxyArr = update.getProxyArr();
        portArr = update.getPortArr();
        count = update.getCount();
        queryResult = update.getResult();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.assist_update_btn:
            switch (mInstructionNumber) {

            }
            // public void onClick(View v) {
            // if (v == mAssistUpdateButton) {

            // Update button for ICS and up is selected
            // Get the TextView in the Assist Update UI

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            String text = "";
            CharSequence styledText = text;
            switch (mInstructionNumber) {

            case 0:
                // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
                // 2nd set of instructions
                text = String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                        TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 1:
                text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 2:
                // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

                setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
                String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                        getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
                TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
                assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
                mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
                mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
                mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        //}
    //  switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.assist_instr_btn:
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
            try {
                showNotification();
            } catch (SAXException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                showNotification();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();



//  /   switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.read_again_btn:
            // switch(mInstructionNumber)
            // go back to set of instructions if read again is selected

            TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
        //  String text = "";
            //CharSequence styledText = text;
            switch (mInstructionNumber) {

            case 0:
                // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
                // 2nd set of instructions
                text = String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                        TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
                tv2.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 1:
                text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                tv2.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 2:
                // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

                setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
                String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                        getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
                TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
                assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
                mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
                mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
                mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }
    }

    public ContentValues getValues() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        if (nameArr.size() > 0) {
            values.put("name", nameArr.get(i));
        }
        if (ApnArr.size() > 0) {
            values.put("apn", ApnArr.get(i));
        }
        if (mmscArr.size() > 0) {
            values.put("mmsc", mmscArr.get(i));
        }
        if (mmsproxyArr.size() > 0) {
            values.put("mmsproxy", mmsproxyArr.get(i));
        }
        if (mmsportArr.size() > 0) {
            values.put("mmsport", mmsportArr.get(i));
        }
        if (proxyArr.size() > 0) {
            values.put("proxy", proxyArr.get(i));
        }
        if (portArr.size() > 0) {
            values.put("port", portArr.get(i));
        }
        values.put("mcc", (getString(R.string.mcc)));
        if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_tmo));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_tmo)));
        } else if ((tm.getSimOperator())
                .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_att));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_att)));
        }
        values.put("type", getString(R.string.type));
        return values;
    }

    // showAlert displays the text contained in message as an alert
    public void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                ConfigFinalActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        mErrorAlert = builder.create();
        mErrorAlert.show();
    }

    // showErrorAlert displays an alert with layout and a title
    private void showErrorAlert(int layoutRes, String title) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = ConfigFinalActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setTitle(title)
        .setView(inflater.inflate(layoutRes, null))
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.assisted_button),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                startActivity(new Intent(
                        Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
                try {
                    showNotification();
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        mErrorAlert = builder.create();
        mErrorAlert.show();
    }

    // showNotification starts the process of sending notifications to the bar
    // to assist the user in updating the data settings on ICS and later
    // versions of Android
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    void showNotification() throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {

        String field = getString(R.string.config_name_label);

        String value = Values.get("name").toString();
        int mId = 1;
        String title = "1 of " + TotalSteps + " (Update " + field + ":)";
        Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifications_icon)
        .setContentTitle(title).setContentText(value);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this,
                NotificationActivityForMultiProf.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra(field, value);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotification = mBuilder.getNotification();
        mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mNotification);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mNotification != null) {
            outState.putString("NOTIFICATIONB", mNotification.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if (mErrorAlert != null)
            mErrorAlert.dismiss();
    }

    private int updateTable() throws IOException, SAXException,
    ParserConfigurationException {
        int insertResult = -1;
        // returned value if table is not properly updated

        try {

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            // Query the carrier table for the current data settings
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(APN_TABLE_URI, null,
                    "current=?", new String[] { "1" }, null);

            values = SettingsDbAdapter.copyRecordFields(c);
            // Copy the NET10 settings into values

            // Replace T-Mo/ATT Data settings if there is no SIM or
            // StraightTalk/T-Mo/ATT SIM is
            // present
            if (tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                    .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {

                // delete all APNs before adding new APNs

                SettingsDbAdapter.DeleteAPNs("numeric=?",
                        new String[] { getString(R.string.numeric_att) },
                        ConfigFinalActivity.this);
                // Insert StraightTalk Data Settings into Carrier table

                insertResult = SettingsDbAdapter.InsertAPN(count,
                        ConfigFinalActivity.this);

            } else if (tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                    .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
                // Delete all APNs before adding new APNs

                SettingsDbAdapter.DeleteAPNs("numeric=?",
                        new String[] { getString(R.string.numeric_att) },
                        ConfigFinalActivity.this);
                // Insert Straight Talk Data Settings into Carrier table

                insertResult = SettingsDbAdapter.InsertAPN(count,
                        ConfigFinalActivity.this);

            } else
                // non Straight Talk/ non T-Mo SIM/non ATT SIM
                showAlert(getString(R.string.insert_sm_dialog));
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            showErrorAlert(R.layout.assisted_setting,
                    getString(R.string.assited_title));
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return insertResult;
    }

    private void completeUpdate() {
        // Displaying final layout after pre-ICS automatic settings update
        setContentView(R.layout.completion);
        TextView mCompleted = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.done_text);
        String mDoneText = String.format(getString(R.string.done_text));
        CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(mDoneText);

        mCompleted.setText(styledText);
        mXButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.x_button);
        mXButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void tryagain() {
        // Displaying final layout after failure of pre-ICS automatic settings
        // update
        setContentView(R.layout.tryagain);
        String tryAgainText = "";
        CharSequence styledTryAgainText;

        tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text1),
                TotalSteps);
        styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
        TextView tryAgain1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text1);
        tryAgain1.setText(styledTryAgainText);

        tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text2),
                TotalSteps);
        styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
        TextView tryAgain2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text2);
        tryAgain2.setText(styledTryAgainText);

        tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text3),
                TotalSteps);
        styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
        TextView tryAgain3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text3);
        tryAgain3.setText(styledTryAgainText);

    }

    // This function return a cursor to the table holding the
    // the APN configurations (Carrier table)
    public Cursor getConfigTableCursor() {
        return getContentResolver()
                .query(APN_TABLE_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you added `android:clickable="true"` to your `TextView`? If so, have you set a breakpoint to see if the function is not getting called or if there is something going wrong inside the `onClick()`?

Comment: Have you added textView.onClickListner(this) to your textView?

Comment: Are you sure that onClick is getting called?  Add a log statement before the conditional or step through in debugger. Show us the code where you connect your listener to your Textview.  Also, are you implementing OnClickListener in you class?

Comment: I connect my listener to my textview here... mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
    mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to compare objects with the `==` operator.  Try something like this instead:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.yourButton:
            switch(mInstructionNumber) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                ...
            }
        case R.id.ofmAssistInstrButton:
        case R.id.ofmAssistInstrButton: //I think you made a typo here since they are the same name
        default:
            //your else statement stuff
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Something along the lines of: public void onClick(View v) {
     switch(v.getId()) {
         case R.id.mAssistUpdateButton  

?

Comment: @Wendy Is that what you named it in your layout file?

Comment: No... in my layout file it is called R.id.read_again_btn


mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
    mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: @Wendy Try it like this then: `public void onClick(View v) { switch(v.getId()) { case R.id.read_again_btn...`

Comment: I did... I'm still having issues. It was suggested that I switch back to the method I used in this post. stackoverflow.com/questions/19036680/onclick-listener-does-not-change-text-as-expected (which leaves me back where I started unable to use the mReadAgainButton to start the sequence of text over again.

Comment: @Wendy You did not change it like I asked.  The outer switch, like how I show, should be switching based on the ID of the `View` being passed into `onClick()`.  For some reason you are still comparing the views using the `==` which is what I said not to do.

Comment: I updated my source using the method you suggested... however I still cannot seem to use switch(v.getId()) { 
           case R.id.read_again_btn:  to start the text sequence again from the beginning

Comment: @Wendy Why are you are still using the `==` operator in places... you need to convert those into cases for your switch(v.getId()).  For example, `if (v == mAssistInstrButton)` and `else if (v == mAssistInstrButton)` should be converted into cases and the `else` should be converted to a default case.  I updated my post again.

Comment: I apologize... I updated my source above again (see anything I might have done wrong?)

Comment: @Wendy That looks more correct, but just so you know you don't need a `switch (v.getId())` for each case, you can combine them into one.  What is the error?

Comment: @Wendy You are using `R.id.assist_update_btn` as a case in two separate switches which means it will run for both of them if that button is pressed which I don't think you want to do.

Comment: I updated it again... it's causing an error on the line: String value = Values.get("name").toString();

which is outside the context of the original post - I think I have it from here (unless you have any suggestions as to why what I've done here would affect this line [it worked previously])

Comment: @Wendy Your last update looks much better.  I'm assuming `values` is a hashmap, which means that `get()` will return a null value if it does not find what it's looking for.  Try to debug to make sure that `"name"` has a value associated with it in the map.  In your first example, you called `Values = getValues()` which I don't see you doing in your new code, so maybe `Values` is null?

Comment: It shouldn't be... the only thing I've changed is the onclick listeners and it was fully functional just before I changed it. : ( 

I'm 99.99% pretty sure if I roll my code back it will work fine.

Comment: @Wendy I'm confused, in your OP you said that it wasn't working so how did you tell it was functional?  I'm pretty sure the problem is you aren't calling `Values = getValues()` anywhere in the new code so it is still null.

Comment: I am calling it... I can post my entire code as long as it isn't a nuisance. (and I had it working before my OP - my onclick listener for my readagain wasn't doing anything - but I was able to get the data for Values) one sec... I'll post my full code.