# OnClick Listener Does Not Change Text As Expected

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm attempting to use an onclick listener on mAssistUpdateButton as well as mReadAgainButton however neither seems to change the visible text.

Any suggestions as to what I may have done wrong are greatly appreciated.

SOURCE:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == mAssistUpdateButton) {

        // Update button for ICS and up is selected
        // Get the TextView in the Assist Update UI

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
        String text = "";
        CharSequence styledText = text;
        switch(v.getId()) {

        //case R.id.read_again_btn {

        case 0:
            // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
            // 2nd set of instructions
            text = String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                    TotalSteps);
            styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
            // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
            tv.setText(styledText);
            // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
            // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
            // button is pressed
            mInstructionNumber++;
            break;
        case 1:
            text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
            styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
            tv.setText(styledText);
            // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
            // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
            // button is pressed
            mInstructionNumber++;
            break;
        case 2:
            // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

            setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
            String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                    getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
            styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
            TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
            assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
            mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
            mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
            mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }// end switch

        }// end if
        else if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {
        // "LET'S DO THIS" Button in final instructions screen for ICS and
        // up is selected
        Values = getValues();
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
        try {
            showNotification();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finish();
        }// end if
        else if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
        try {
            showNotification();
        } catch (SAXException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            showNotification();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finish();

        }// end if
        else if (v == mReadAgainButton) {
        // go back to set of instructions if read again is selected

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
        String text = "";
        CharSequence styledText = text;

        switch (mInstructionNumber) {

        case 0:
            // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
            // 2nd set of instructions
            text = String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                    TotalSteps);
            styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
            // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
            tv.setText(styledText);
            // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
            // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
            // button is pressed
            mInstructionNumber++;
            break;
        case 1:
            text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
            styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
            tv.setText(styledText);
            // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
            // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
            // button is pressed
            mInstructionNumber++;
            break;
        case 2:
            // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

            setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
            String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                    getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
            styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
            TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
            assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
            mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
            mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
            mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            break;
             }// end switch
           }
        }
```

Comment: use Button id's instead of 0,1,2,... in switch-case to execute code according to Button click

Comment: Wendy, your case has to equal the value for the view's ID.  Instead of case 0, it should say case R.id.your_button.

Comment: Inside the if-condition for the `mAssistUpdateButton` you're switching on the view ID with cases of `0`, `1` and `2`. However, view IDs will *never* have those values. The other buttons seems to suffer similar logic, although the switch takes place on `mInstructionNumber`. Not sure what you meant to do with that, but as soon as it goes over `2`, it becomes useless (at least, I don't see it being decremented anywhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v.getId()` returns the `id` of the `View` (`v`) that was passed to the `onClick()`.

You are checking if your `id` of the `View` is 0,1,2,etc...

```
case 0:
```

Your `case` statements should be an `id` of a `View`.

```
case R.id.mAssistUpdateButton:
    // do your work if that button was clicked
```

I'm not sure what you expect them to be but check [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fjava%2Fnutsandbolts%2Fswitch.html&ei=B4hEUpEpkOqoAZPqgDg&usg=AFQjCNFhoN_wBL-k4csTfvsMnCQnDtqTiw&sig2=HVMKGalTnehzHlseNVJxCw&bvm=bv.53217764,d.aWM)

**Edit**

Now that you have explained what you are trying to do, you could create a member variable that is a counter and declare it as an `int`. Then you can keep the `case` statements as you have them but change the `switch` to

```
switch (counterVariable){
```

Please read the link I posted so you understand `switch` statements but what you do is compare the variable in the `switch` to the `case` options to determine which block of code to run.

You would obviously want to increase your counter variable by one each time you enter the `onClick()`.

Comment: What should I use for the 2nd case after case R.id.assist_update_btn: ? I'm getting duplicate case errors when attempting to use to more than once throughout the sequence

Comment: (i need to click it multiple times and each time display new text)

Comment: "Ohhhh ohhhh it's maaagic..." : ) 

P.S.

I tried using this method initially and it worked for changing the case up until it reached the "mReadAgainButton" then the onclick listener failed there... (you were helping with that too - any idea what I did wrong in that implementation?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035094/onclick-listener-is-not-function-as-expected

Comment: Not sure...could be several things. You would need to set breakpoints and see exactly where it is stopping. My initial guess would be, as my comment stated, that the `TextView` wasn't set to clickable. Or your `OnClickListener` wasn't set up correctly.

Comment: It is set to clickable in the XML... did you see anything that could be incorrect with my onclick listener? I used:       mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
              mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Nope, it looks fine. Did you set a breakpoint inside there to see if it enters that part of the code? It could be getting there but something else causing a problem. Did it crash? Also it should be `if (v.getId() == R.id.read_again_btn)` that would be safer.